# Как сделать правильно точку входа для в класс?

Tags: php

Приходят данные `$_POST, $_GET` с параметром `type`, где `type` указывает на тип поиска. (поиск по статья, новостям). 
Для каждого типа поиска написан свой класс.
Как будет красиво сделать точку входа для передачи объекта классам в зависимости от `type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface SearchWorker {
   public function search($params);
}
class ArticleSearch implements SearchWorker {
  public function search($params) {
     //code here
  }
}

class SearchService {
  protected $workers = ['article' => 'ArticleSearch'];

  public function find($type, $params) {
    if(isset($this->workers[$type])) {
       $worker = new $this->workers[$type];
       return $worker->search($params);
    } else {
      throw new Exception('undefined search type'); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не шутите с данными, которые к вам приходят извне.

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
switch($type) {
    case 'type1':
    $search = new Type1();
    break;
    case 'type2':
    $search = new Type2();
    break;
    default:
    $search = new TypeDefault();
}
```

Comment: Да вы правы, но вопрос именно звучал, как сделать так, как хотят. То, что данные надо проверить, это однозначно, к примеру в том же скрипте автолоадера можно попробовать проверить существование файла класса и выкинуть exception, кроме того, данные, которые пришли в любом случае, я думаю, обрабатываются типа так, к примеру:

    if(in_array(trim($_GET['type']),array('news','articles','lists'))) тогда делай что-то.

Comment: Есть другие варианты? Может, фабричный метод или другой паттерн?

Comment: Можно и не автолоадером, а class_exists. Если они уже загружены.

Answer (score 1):

```
$type = 'имя класса';

$search = new $type();
```

В вашем случае должно быть что-то такое: `$type = trim($_GET['type']);`
Для подгрузки классов воспользуйтесь автолоадером:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {include $class_name . '.php';}
$type = trim($_GET['type']);
$search = new $type();
```